# Entity Framework Code First: Entity Splitting

Tags: frameworks, entity

Is it possible to map the following scenario?

**Data Tables**

Students

+ ID: int PK 
+ Name: varchar(200)

Classes

+ ID: int PK 
+ StudentID: FK 
+ CourseID: FK 
+ EnrollmentDate: DateTime

Courses

+ ID: int PK
+ Name: varchar(200)

I would like to map the tables to entities below.

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes {get;set;}
}
```

```
public class Class
{
[Key]
public int ID {get;set;}
public Student Student {get;set;}
public DateTime EnrollmentDate {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;} // this comes from the Courses data table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be how to establish the FK relationships you require:

```
public class Student
{
   [Key]
   public int StudentId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Class
{
   [Key]
   public int ClassId {get;set;}
   public DateTime EnrollmentDate {get;set;}

   //foreign keys
   public int CourseId {get;set;}
   public string StudentId {get;set;} 

   //virtual constraint to link to referenced tables
   public virtual Course Course {get;set;}
   public virtual Student Student {get;set;}
}

public class Course
{
   [Key]
   public int CourseId {get;set;}
   public string CourseName {get;set;}
}
```